# Coding JavaScript in Adobe Acrobat Professional

Tags: javascript

I'll soon be coding some JavaScript in Adobe Acrobat Pro, but I hate coding in notepad because it doesn't show me my mistakes. I know the JavaScript implemented by Acrobat Pro is a little different from web JavaScript. I'm wondering if there are software (Visual Studio, Notepad ++ or the like) that would help me highlight my code and help me catch errors. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend [Komodo Edit](https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-edit/) for just this reason. It catches and highlights about 95% errors of my simple mistakes. This IDE and that feature increased my productivity more than any other tool since I started coding. No more hunting for that trailing comma, or a period where a semi colon should be; it catches your unpaired parenthesis and brackets... it's great.

Autocomplete is nice too, especially for CSS. But make sure to turn off "Enable autocomplete fill-up characters" (Preferences -> Code Intelligence). With that on, the autocomplete runs wild on you.